# UrlFetchApp returns Error 404 on every call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Suddenly today I started getting Error 404 while using the script with UrlFetchApp which was working fine till yesterday.

My script is as below:

```js
const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?function=";

function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.function == "Protect") {
    script();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput();
  }
  else if (e.parameter.function == "AddRows" ) {
    Addrows(e.parameter.sheetName,e.parameter.notoAdd);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput();
  }
  else { // do something by default if there are no url parameters
    throw new Error("function was not found.");
    
  }
}

function Protect() {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "Protect", {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
}
```

> Message details
> Exception: Request failed for https://script.google.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: <meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

When option muteHttpExceptions : flase is used the same error is generated.

Please let me know what suddenly changed in the scripts as I am getting the same error in various other codes also.

Comment: Can you confirm that you didn't make any change to the script nor to the deployment settings prior to noticing this change in behavior?

Comment: Also, make sure that the url returned by `getUrl()` matches the URL of the web app deployment you are trying to access. Chances are that's not the case.

Comment: I did not make any changes or deployments suddenly today it started giving this error.

Comment: When i Add option as muteHttpExceptions: true in UrlFetchApp the error is not shown and the script is shown as finished but the desired function is not called

Comment: Can you check whether the url returned by `getUrl()` matches the URL of the web app deployment you are trying to access?

Comment: Just did its the same: From Deployment Page the URL is https://script.google.com/a/macros/rasi.com/s/AKfycbzZFkQ5YCzletlcQ6coCUV9ShD6WciuW61nr-zOlXcDvUId9VwJ/exec while from fetchurl is https://script.google.com/a/rasi.com/macros/s/AKfycbzZFkQ5YCzletlcQ6coCUV9ShD6WciuW61nr-zOlXcDvUId9VwJ/exec?function there is change in placement of website name from fetchurl how can i edit this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234811/discussion-between-harsh-and-iamblichus).

Comment: I redeployed new version of each and every project and then again it started working thanks for all the help